# Error accessing field X by reflection for persistent property X

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, spring-boot

I have 2 classes, TransportOrder and LardiSendedOrder. It's bounded by field `innerId`, and I just want list all records from  LardiSendedOrder table, but got this error.

```
Error accessing field [private java.lang.Integer com.example.model.LardiSendedOrder.innerId] by reflection for persistent property [com.example.model.LardiSendedOrder#innerId] : 1;
```

class Transport Order

```
@Entity
    class TransportOrder {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;
    private String url;
    private String source;
    private String transport;
    private Date start_date;
    private Date end_date;
    private String start_address;
    private String end_address;
    private ArrayList<String> phones =new ArrayList<>()
    private Integer distance;
    private String content;
    private String weight;
    private String size;
    private Boolean fromVendor;
    private ArrayList<PaymentType> payment_type = new ArrayList<PaymentType>();
    private Double payment;
    private String payment_by;
    private ArrayList<PaymentEvent> payment_event = new ArrayList<PaymentEvent>();
    private Date add_date;
    @NotNull
    @Column(unique=true)
    private Integer hashCode;

    LardiSendedOrder getLardiSendedOrder() {
        return lardiSendedOrder
    }

    void setLardiSendedOrder(LardiSendedOrder lardiSendedOrder) {
        this.lardiSendedOrder = lardiSendedOrder
    }
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(
           /* referencedColumnName = "innerId"*/
            referencedColumnName = "innerId"
    )
    private LardiSendedOrder lardiSendedOrder;

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

//another getters and setters omitted
}
```

class LardiSendedOrder

```
@Entity
class LardiSendedOrder {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;

    private Integer innerId;

    private Integer outerId;

    private Date publish_date;

    Integer getUserId() {
        return userId
    }

    void setUserId(Integer userId) {
        this.userId = userId
    }
    private Integer userId;

    TransportOrder getTransportOrder() {
        return transportOrder
    }

    void setTransportOrder(TransportOrder transportOrder) {
        this.transportOrder = transportOrder
    }
    @OneToOne(
            cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
            fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
             mappedBy = "lardiSendedOrder")
    private TransportOrder transportOrder;

    Integer getInnerId() {
        return innerId
    }

    void setInnerId(Integer innerId) {
        this.innerId = innerId
    }

    Integer getOuterId() {
        return outerId
    }

    void setOuterId(Integer outerId) {
        this.outerId = outerId
    }

    String getPublish_date() {
        return publish_date.format("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss");;
    }

    void setPublish_date(Date publish_date) {
        this.publish_date = publish_date
    }
}
```

And i just call

```
   ArrayList<LardiSendedOrder> orders = (ArrayList<LardiSendedOrder>) lardiSendedOrderRepository.findAll();
```

Comment: Why don't you map `lardiSendedOrder` by its id, i.e. the field `id`? As it is the JPA provider would have to assume `innerId` could be null or non-unique (even though that might be directly related to the error you get). - And how are `LardiSendedOrder` and `TransportOrder` related? They are in different hierarchies and thus probably also represent different tables. Also if `innerId` is meant to be the id of `transportOrder` where's the mapping for that?

Comment: I don't map it, because not all transportOrders will have corresponding
 record in LardiSenedOrder. **how are LardiSendedOrder and TransportOrder related?** - I have many orders, some of it will have record in lardiSendedOrder, so they related transportOrder.id =lardiSendedOrder.innerId. I   I specified this using the annotation `@JoinColumn(ReferencedColumnName = "innerId")`, maybe i was wrong?

Comment: I still don't get what you're trying to do. If not every `LardiSendedOrder` has a `TransportOrder` then just make that relation nullable. If not every `TransportOrder` has a corresponding `LardiSendedOrder` then make that relation unidirectional as well.

Comment: Yeah, i solve it by reading more examples. Problem was in my wrong understanding  `mappedBy` directive, so i done some changes in code and all working well)